# Laravel: Since symfony/http-foundation 5.2: The "HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL" constant is deprecated

Tags: php, laravel

After upgrading to PHP8 and one day later adding [Mailcoach](https://mailcoach.app) I'm getting the following error:

`Since symfony/http-foundation 5.2: The "HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL" constant is deprecated, use either "HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR | HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST | HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT | HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO" or "HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB" or "HEADER_X_FORWARDED_TRAEFIK" constants instead.`

`composer update` runs without any errors.

Searching for this doesn't give me any results, especially not related to Laravel. There must be something that I'm missing.

The stack trace starts in `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(...)` and indicates it happens at `$request = Request::capture()`.

My knowledge of all this is too limited to know what to look for or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This also occurred to me because I have an SSL Filter set as a middleware in my Laravel application and because it uses `HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL` and that header was deprecated in the newer version of symfony, I received the same warnings as you.  To correct it, I did exactly what the error message suggests and changed my request to `HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR` which solved the problem.

In reading the code here: https://github.com/spatie/Mailcoach/tree/main/app/Http/Middleware

it appears that MailCoach is also written with the Laravel Framework and that it recently updated the code to correct the issue. You can see the reference on the TrustProxies Middleware.  I'd upgrade your instance of Mailcoach however you installed it to address the issue, or update the deprecated header.